# Mapping LDAP groups to existing keycloak groups

Tags: keycloak

By following the keycloak documentation:  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_ldap_mappers

I created a group mapper like this:
[image]

But I don't see an option to give the name keycloak group so that the imported ldap group can be mapped to this group.

Instead , when I **"Sync LDAP Groups to Keycloak Groups"** , a new group with the name of ldap group is created.

Any idea how to map existing ldap groups to a single keycloak group ?

Comment: Updated link: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_ldap_mappers

Answer (score 2):

Default LDAP Provider doesn't provide this option, the only way is custom federation provider. Override this logic in it if you need. ImportSynchronization interface is responsible for it.

Comment: Can you share an example or a link to a sample?

Comment: I didn't implement the ldap, just custom REST provider, here is the source code for ldap, just copy it and override necessary methods for your logic. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap